# Model in Unity AR is not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, ar-foundation

I have a problem with Unity AR when I place any object in the scene. The 3D object is not showing on the AR camera or when I run the scene in a real device, just blank.

I'm sure I imported the needed packages like AR Foundation, ARCore, and XR. Also the AR Session and AR Session Origin.

[image: The apple is not showing]

Answer (score 0):

There are too many reasons why a 3D model may not be visible (rendered) in Unity AR, but the most common reasons are as follows:

- Unsupported smartphone model
- Absence of 3D lighting
- Incorrect render settings
- Model is out of frustum (far clipping plane)
- Camera is inside a model
- Model is too big (or too small)
- The model is behind you